# Super ultrawide monitor + KVM. PC/Mac

Tags: displays, kvm

I have the Dell **U4919DW** which has been a great monitor. While working with just two PC's it has a built in KVM which was easy to flip back and forth between. Going to two pc's + a mac I made it work, but their integrated software made switching a little awkward. There's no capability to go to 4 or more that I could figure out.

I'm looking for a KVM switch that will support this monitor along with 2 macbook pros, a pc with a 1080ti, and a laptop with an integrated amd graphics. I don't mind buying cables to convert signals to whatever they need too. I'm not a competitive gamer so 60hz for me has been fine. I currently use the [Tesmart 4 port DP 1.2 KVM switch](https://www.tesmart.com/products/tesmart-4x1-dp-kvm-switch-4k-60hz-ultra-hd-mechanical-multimedia-keyboards-usb-2-0-devices4-in-1-out-display-port-kvm-switcher-dp-control-up-to-4-dp-port-devices) but it doesn't have EDID emulation so my windows fly around everywhere anytime I switch. I'm currently using PersistentWindows which is *ok*.

I had initially bought their [HDMI KVM switch](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0874PP99K/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) but after a bit of troubleshooting with them it didn't look like it'd supported the 5440x1440 that the Dell needed so I returned it for the DP one.